# Bootstrap dropdowns and other components don't work in the side menu (Sidr plugin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, sidr

I'm trying to use dropdown inside the side menu. The side menu is implemented using the jQuery plugin called [Sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/)

You can see it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfnRK/80/)

[image: The side menu and content page]

I expect the dropdown inside the side menu to be like in the image below. In fact when I place the code outside of the side menu it works (correct styles are applyed and it can be opened and closed).

[image: The working dropdown (outside the side menu)]

But when the same code placed inside the side menu it looks like the bootstrap styles and jquery are not working properly. I can't figure out why it's happening.

[image: Not working dropdown (inside the side menu)]

**HTML**

```
    <!-- Link to open the side menu -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#left-menu">Open</a>
    <!-- The side menu itself -->
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <div class="container">               
            <!-- Single button -->
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                    Action <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {    
    $('.navbar-brand').sidr({
        name: 'sidr-left',
        side: 'left', 
        source: '.nav-collapse'
    });
    //this code is close sidr menu if clicked outside
    $(document).bind("click", function () {
        $.sidr('close', 'sidr-left');
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.sidr
{
    background: #f8f8f8;
    color: #333;
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: absolute;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 260px;
    z-index: 999999;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 1px #777;
}
.sidr .sidr-inner
{
    padding:15px;
}
.sidr.left
{
    left: -260px;
    right: auto;
}
```

How to make it recognize bootstrap components and its functionality?

Comment: Are you including reference to the bootstrap css?

Comment: I include  /css/bootstrap.css to the html file that's why when I put that code outside the div.nav-collapse it works

Comment: I tried to make snippet using your code but it does not work. I think something is missing in this code you wrote here.

Comment: I added jsfiddle and pic with dropdowns inside the side menu(strange rendering) and outside it(working dropdown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid overriding the bootstrap functionality the property `renaming: false` should be added

```
$('.navbar-brand').sidr({
    name: 'sidr-left',
    side: 'left', 
    source: '.nav-collapse',
    renaming: false//<--
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mfnRK/81/)